# Output of the Python program is coming as 'None'

Tags: python, recursion

```
def fact(n, summ):
    if n == 0:
        print(summ)  -- Prints 55
        return summ
    fact(n-1, summ + n)


print(fact(10, 0))  -- Output None
```

Comment: You need to use `return fact(n-1, summ + n)`

Comment: Yes I understand, but why does it return 'None' if I return it from inside the IF block ?

Comment: @Dhruv The linked question has answers for your query.

Comment: @Dhruv Because it only returns from the block when `n == 0`, so `None` is implicitly returned if nothing else is. Think of the flow of data between recurses. Every path of execution must return something or that data is lost.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Thanks, got the point. So silly of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `fact(n-1, summ + n)` as a returning value. If a function does not return a value then it defaults to returning None.

```
def fact(n, summ):
    if n == 0:
        return summ
    return fact(n-1, summ + n)

print(fact(10, 0))
```

This outputs:

```
55
```

On a side note, your `fact` function could be re-implemented without the second parameter. The following produces the same output:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return n + fact(n-1)

print(fact(10))
```